# How to change integer type when creating meshgrid with Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I got the following error

> MemoryError: Unable to allocate 201. GiB for an array with shape
> (2999, 2999, 2999) and data type int64

when creating a meshgrid with Numpy using the following code

```
dimension=3
tot_length=2000
list_no=range(1, tot_length)
arr = np.meshgrid ( *[list_no for _ in range ( dimension )] )
```

May I know where to change the int64 to int32 or, other possible setting that can allow me to maximize the number of `tot_length` which is higher than the value `2000`

I have check the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html), but it does not stated option to change the data type to type32.

Comment: What is `rows` on line 3? your code only defines `rows_1`?

Comment: Hi Eric, I have updated the variable name for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> May I know where to change the int64 to int32

NumPy is guessing `int64` because you are giving it a `range` object where it expects an array, and `range`s are sequences of `int`. Use an array if you want it not to guess:

```
list_no = np.array(range(1, tot_length), dtype=np.int32)
```

or more simply

```
list_no = np.arange(1, tot_length, dtype=np.int32)
```

Of course, you'll still need 100 GiB of memory, which is still quite large.

Comment: Yes, 100 Gb is still large. Thanks for the insight

Comment: Hi Eric, regarding the memory issue, appreciate if you can offer some insight here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64450286/6446053